# Firefox downloading torrents gives me no application to open them with - just opens download folder

Tags: firefox, bittorrent, deluge

When I download a torrent it asks me to choose an application to open it with but it shows none - even though I have deluge and qbittorrent installed. Clicking on "choose app" takes me to the download folder - no apps there.

Why are no apps recognised? And how do I find them?

Ubuntu 12.04 on Lenovo T500 with Firefox browser.

Comment: Are you downloading the torrent file and then trying to open it from Firefox's "Downloads" panel?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the torrent file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default behavior of Firefox. When you download a file that can be opened with an application it ask you. You can save the file and go to download folder and open it from there

or search in **/usr/bin** to locate deluge.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the help! It took a bit to figure out how to get to bin but deluge was there and the torrent is downloading now. Deluge is now marked as 'preferred' so hopefully no more problems there.

Comment: Glad to help. If the question is solved, then mark it as such. (as that your question has been answered).

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but where do i mark the post as solved? Not at all clear!

Comment: [Take the tour](http://askubuntu.com/about)

Comment: took the tour and no answer as how to mark as solved. Could you just tell me how?