# I can't find the file 'transmission' on my computer with the search function

Tags: 13.04, firefox, search, bittorrent, transmission

I went to download a torrent today and Firefox asked me to choose an application to do so (although the bit torrent files normally go to transmission per the permissions I've set in Firefox).  I go to search for transmission and the search function just turns up music files with the letters 'tran' in them. I'm very frustrated.  I literally can't find the path to a file that's on my computer.

Comment: Are you sure you did not remove transmission? If it ever was used before and is still present you should see it in dash. What happens if you open a terminal and type ` transmission-gtk`? Does  it start transmission? And does dash then show it again?

Comment: I have transmission opened.  It's definitely on the system.  When I click a torrent link, Firefox asks me to choose an application to open it.  I've already told firefox what to do with bittorrent seeds.  Now I'm looking in .cache and .config and I have two transmission folders but neither one has an application file that firefox will accept.

Comment: Ok, I found some help here

http://askubuntu.com/questions/316020/firefox-downloading-torrents-gives-me-no-application-to-open-them-with-just-op

But... when I found the transmission-gtk file, it has a ? sign instead of a disk image.  Any thoughts?  It's still not working.  When I download the torrent, the box says there's no torrent there.

Answer (score 1):

For the GTK+ client, all settings are kept in `~/.config/transmission`

For the Daemon, all settings are kept in `~/.config/transmission-daemon`

For the CLI, all settings are kept in `~/.config/transmission-cli`

The default download folder is `~/Downloads`

The transmission torrents file is located in `~/.config/transmission/torrents`

Executable file location

[image]