# Can't set Transmission to download files

Tags: 12.04, firefox, downloads, bittorrent, transmission

Just installed Ubuntu 12. on my new computer. When trying to download files I want to use Transmission but after I choose a file to download Transmission is not in the list of programs to run with (infact it's empty) and when I click "Choose a program" (or whatever it says in english") and find the folder Transmission there's no file or program to choose from (I also choose "show hidden files", the folders within the Transmission folder are empty exept for settings.json. When I go to the list of settings in Firefox, Transmission are not among these and I don't know how to add it. Please, help. Want to getting started downloadning again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get Firefox to open torrent files with Transmission?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/384375/how-can-i-get-firefox-to-open-torrent-files-with-transmission), you can check also [Firefox downloading torrents gives me no application to open them with - just opens download folder](http://askubuntu.com/questions/316020/firefox-downloading-torrents-gives-me-no-application-to-open-them-with-just-op)

Answer (score 0):

Look in the `/usr/bin` folder for "transmission" or "transmission-gtk".

Comment: Nothing to do with Traensmission in that folder. Bunch of other "files" but not the two above.